# Entity Framework 6 compatibility with ODAC

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I have a project that uses EF 6. So far I've been using SQL CE for development purposes, but time has come to integrate the project with an Oracle database.

I installed Oracle Data Access Components for Oracle Client 12.1.0.1.2 and noticed that I was having problems integrating it into my project. I came upon [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2619480) where the accepted answer is stating that "EF 6 is not supported by ODAC 12c R2".

However, a few messages below the accepted answer, the same person [says](https://community.oracle.com/message/12311402#12311402):

> ODP.NET is EF 6 compatible. It is not EF 6 certified. I explained the
>   distinction verbally in the presentation. The doc does explain the
>   distinction. It says **ODP.NET in ODAC 12c R2 can run in EF 6, but you
>   must set EF to use an earlier framework version (i.e. EF 5).** That is
>   what is meant by EF 6 compatible. You can use ODP.NET with EF 5 inside
>   an EF 6 instance. You cannot run ODP.NET natively running on EF 6.

I have 2 questions:

1. What exactly does it mean: "You can use ODP.NET with EF 5 inside an
   EF 6 instance"?
2. Is it possible to use EF 6 in my case, or should I spend some gloomy
   time downgrading to EF 5?

Thank you.

Comment: I have bolded the relevant words in that passage.  I was unaware that you could set EF6 for backwards compatibility with EF5.  The words "use ODP.NET with EF 5 inside an EF 6 instance" are just the author's way of saying "Set EF6 for EF5 compatibility."

Comment: He also mentions the "Framework Version," which suggests setting your project target framework to an earlier version, but that doesn't sound right to me.  You might want to clarify that with him; I'm not at all sure what he means.

Comment: It is possible to use ODP.NET with EF6. I have used it in my project and it is working well enough.Further running EF with backward compatibility is news to me.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for your comments. Unfortunately, I have no idea what exactly am I supposed to do to "set EF6 for EF5 compatibility". Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Ash, could you please provide some more information on how you managed to achieve this?

Comment: At the moment I'm stuck here: System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'.
 Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider. This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later.

Comment: This might help: http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/06/EF6-Breaking-Changes